# Using ffprobe/ffmpeg to extract individual frames and types in encode order

Tags: python, ffmpeg, keyframe, ffprobe

I am able to extract keyframes using ffmpeg. Something like this that I have been using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 I-thumbnails-%02d.png -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,B)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 B-thumbnails-%02d.png -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,P)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 P-thumbnails-%02d.png
```

Now the issue is, I would like these extracted frames to be in encode order, if possible, the way they are extracted should have a timestamp or any way to know that they start in a certain sequence, example, from start to end:

> IBBBIPPB......BI

but in a way that I can sort the frames in the encode sequence.

I want to use this to load in python to extract motion vectors but they should all follow the encoding sequence. Any help?

**Edit:**
Changed playback to encode sequence(or order).

Comment: A way I came around with was to run besides the above code, run also: "ffprobe input.mp4 -show_frames | grep -E 'pict_type|coded_picture_number' > output.txt" but then I would have to program separately in python to use the text information to match with the returned I, P, B frames. 

Is there any other way to do this easier with ffmpeg only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a recent version of ffmpeg, you can run,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
  -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%02d-I.png
  -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,B)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%02d-B.png
  -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,P)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%02d-P.png
```

The image serial numbers will correspond to their index position (display-wise) in the video, and the suffix will indicate the frame type.

---

To get frames in encode/decode order, run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
  -vf "setpts=POS,select='eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%09d-I.png
  -vf "setpts=POS,select='eq(pict_type\,B)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%09d-B.png
  -vf "setpts=POS,select='eq(pict_type\,P)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%09d-P.png
```

You should sort the output image listing in alphabetical/lexical order - that's the images in encode/decode order. You can batch rename the 9-digit field to a simple serial index, if wanted.

`setpts=POS` sets the frame's timestamp to its byte offset in the file, which will track the encode/decode order.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I would like the frames to be in the same sequence as if the video is playing. If you see the result returned from  "ffprobe input.mp4 -show_frames | grep -E 'pict_type|coded_picture_number' > output.txt", the "coded_picture_number" starting from 0 to last frame together with "pict_type", is the same sequence I would like from ffmpeg but for the *.png files. Any clue?

Comment: That's not the playback order - that's the encode order. filters process frames in playback order - which is what my command outputs.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ffmpeg version 3.4 and I get "Unrecognized option 'frame_pts'." while running your command and get no output. Any clue?

Comment: You need to use a recent git version.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the updated git. I am using git version 2.15.1

Comment: Where did you get it from? Get a dated binary for your platform from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) or https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163800/discussion-between-helder-and-mulvya).

Comment: the official version of ffmpeg seems not to have this option frame_pts, any other workaround?

Comment: Get the latest git binary from one of the links in my comment above,