# ffmpeg returns 'frame_pts' as unrecognized option

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, keyframe, video-compression

Earlier today I posted a question about frame extration with keyframes per encoding order ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418688/using-ffprobe-ffmpeg-to-extract-individual-frames-and-types-in-encode-order)) and I tried to run the command provided in one of the answers but ffmpeg returns:

```
Unrecognized option 'frame_pts'.
```

Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Any clue how to make ffmpeg to recognize 'frame_pts' option?
The full command that I ran is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 "select='eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 thumbnails-%02d-I.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ffmpeg github information, frame_pts option is added 2 months ago:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/f3e34072aadf20be60c0fae38cbe14ad4581c6a5

Perhaps you should update and/or make sure your version of ffmpeg and libavformat (includes img2enc module that you need) is latest version.
And there is also example lines in the link.

Hope that helps.

Comment: shouldn't it come automatically if one installs ffmpeg from conda or brew?

Comment: yes it should, if you compiled from source you can check manually source code: libavformat/img2enc.c between line 211 to 218 should be include line: `{ "frame_pts",    "use current frame pts for filename", OFFSET(frame_pts),  AV_OPT_TYPE_BOOL, { .i64 = 0 }, 0, 1, ENC }`

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look at it.